# Virtualmin mails not receiving. Two mailfolders in home directory

Tags: vps, webmin, virtualmin

I've installed a vps on ubuntu 18.04 with virtualmin as control panel. Once I create a user in a virtual server, the server automatically creates a 'mail' directory besides the 'Maildir' folder (which is normally used for storing mails via IMAP). The server makes use of postfix.

My folder structure in the user folder is now like this:

```
root@server01:/home/tuppr/homes/dprins# ls -al
total 28
drwxr-x--- 7 dprins@tuppr.nl tuppr 4096 Jan 11 21:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 tuppr           tuppr 4096 Jan 11 21:01 ..
drwx------ 3 dprins@tuppr.nl tuppr 4096 Jan 11 21:02 mail
drwx------ 9 dprins@tuppr.nl tuppr 4096 Jan 11 21:01 Maildir
drwx------ 2 dprins@tuppr.nl tuppr 4096 Jan 11 21:02 .spamassassin
drwxr-xr-x 2 dprins@tuppr.nl tuppr 4096 Jan 11 21:04 .tmp
drwx------ 7 dprins@tuppr.nl tuppr 4096 Jan 11 21:02 .usermin
```

The problem is that incoming mails are strangely enough stored in the 'Maildir' directory, but email clients and webmail don't see it.

My postfix main.cf looks like this:

```
root@server01:/home/tuppr/homes/dprins# cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = server01.dennisprins.nl
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, server01.dennisprins.nl, localhost.dennisprins.nl, , localhost
#relayhost = 
relayhost = vps.transip.email:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
#smtp_tls_security_level = may
allow_percent_hack = no
```

In the 'mail' directory I usually only find some 'dovecot' log files, but no real e-mails. Those are stored in the 'Maildir', but for some reason every e-mailclient I tried doesn't seem to discover the mails stored in that folder. Like it's ignoring those. The webmail client also doesn't see any incoming mails. But they are physically stored in 'Maildir'.

Sending mails, however, is going well. Every mail I sent using a third party email client (on my Mac for example) are stored on the server and the webmail client also sees them in the 'Sent' folder.

My dovecot configuration is also pointing towards 'Maildir'. Executing a `grep` command for '/mail' doesn't show up anything rather than outcommented rules in dovecot.

My usermin mailbox configuration looks like this:

```
root@server01:/etc/dovecot# cat /etc/usermin/mailbox/config
spam_always=0
folder_types=local,ext,pop3,imap
no_mailer=0
server_attach=0
top_buttons=1
mail_dir=/var/spool/mail
mail_dir_qmail=Maildir
mail_file=mbox
shortindex=0
mail_system=4
from_format=1
smtp_ssl=0
pop_locks=1
nologout=1
wrap_width=80
spam_report=
perpage=20
folder_virts=virt,comp
show_to=0
mail_style=0
no_orig_ip=1
html_base64=0
edit_from=0
no_crlf=0
sendmail_path=/usr/lib/sendmail
noindex_hostname=1
from_map=/etc/postfix/virtual
mail_qmail=
pop3_server=localhost
send_mode=localhost
server_name=
smtp_pass=
global_address=
ldap_login=
ldap_quotas=
ldap_base=
smtp_user=
max_attach=
global_address_group=
smtp_port=
ldap_host=
ldap_tls=
max_quota=
ldap_pass=
smtp_auth=
ldap_port=
```

I also read and tried this article:
https://www.virtualmin.com/node/35887
https://www.virtualmin.com/node/36027

I checked literally everything but I can't find out why it's not working. All DNS records are perfectly fine. SPF records as well. Those are already checked. Whenever I delete the 'mail' directory, it's coming back as soon as I use the e-mailaccount (whether it's via a mail client or webmail)

Do you guys have any idea why it's behaving like this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello your configuration is wrong when you do the email configuration, there is no local host, but the DNS you configured for POP3 or SMTP.

they must have SSL configuring.
  Also, the type of sending is not localhost. You must also have a configured port. Whether for SMTP or POP3.
Well basically this file you sent is missing a lot of information

I checked your server to see if there was any wrong configuration. But in reality there is no configuration in this domain that you have posted.
Below are the main settings you should make in your DNS

http tuppr.nl The remote name could not be resolved: 'tuppr.nl' (http://tuppr.nl)

```
spf tuppr.nl DNS Record not found 
dmarc tuppr.nl DNS Record not found 
mx tuppr.nl No DMARC Record found 
mx tuppr.nl DNS Record not found 
dns tuppr.nl DNS Record not found 
mx tuppr.nl DMARC Quarantine / Reject policy not enabled
```

send your feedback